# Spring boot Kafka send objects between different microservices

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

This is my producer microservice kafka configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {

    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapService;

    //producer factory
    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, Object> producerFactory (){
        Map<String, Object> configMap = new HashMap<>();
        configMap.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapService);
        configMap.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        configMap.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);

        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configMap);
    }

    //inviare messaggi
    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate(){
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }
}
```

I send the messages like this:

```
kafkaTemplate.send(TOPIC_NAME, message);
```

I have no problems with the producer,

This is the consumer microservice kafka configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {
    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    
    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, Object> consumerFactory() {
        JsonDeserializer<Object> jsonDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer<>();
        jsonDeserializer.addTrustedPackages("*");
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(), new StringDeserializer(), jsonDeserializer);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, Object>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());

        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        return Map.of(
                ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers,
                ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class,
                ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class,
                ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "testId"
        );
    }
}
```

With the same configuration but with String istead of Object or instead of my custom object I get the following stacktrace:

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: This error handler cannot process 'SerializationException's directly; please consider configuring an 'ErrorHandlingDeserializer' in the value and/or key deserializer
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DefaultErrorHandler.handleOtherException(DefaultErrorHandler.java:149) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.3.jar:2.8.3]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.handleConsumerException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1763) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.3.jar:2.8.3]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1286) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.3.jar:2.8.3]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordDeserializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition kafka-topic-2-0 at offset 25. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseRecord(Fetcher.java:1429) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.access$3400(Fetcher.java:134) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$CompletedFetch.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:1652) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$CompletedFetch.access$1800(Fetcher.java:1488) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:721) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:672) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1277) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1238) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1211) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollConsumer(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1510) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.3.jar:2.8.3]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doPoll(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1500) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.3.jar:2.8.3]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1328) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.3.jar:2.8.3]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1237) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.3.jar:2.8.3]
    ... 3 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: failed to resolve class name. Class not found [com.example.kafkaproducer.model.Message]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.kafkaproducer.model.Message
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.mapping.DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.getClassIdType(DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.java:142) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.3.jar:2.8.3]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.mapping.DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.toJavaType(DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.java:103) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.3.jar:2.8.3]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonDeserializer.java:569) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.3.jar:2.8.3]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseRecord(Fetcher.java:1420) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.0.jar:na]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.kafkaproducer.model.Message
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader.loadClass(RestartClassLoader.java:145) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:284) ~[spring-core-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.mapping.DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.getClassIdType(DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.java:138) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.3.jar:2.8.3]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

Do you have any advice for having producer and consumer in different services?

[EDIT]
I'm adding the listener since it has been asked:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = TOPIC_NAME, groupId = "testId")
public void listener(@Payload Message rcvMessage){

    log.info("message: {}", rcvMessage);

}
```

Note that the Message class is defined in both projects with the same parameters.

[Edit 2]
It now works, I removed the headers in the deserializer like this:

```
@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, Message> consumerFactory() {
    JsonDeserializer<Message> jsonDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer<>(Message.class, false);
    jsonDeserializer.addTrustedPackages("*");
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(), new StringDeserializer(), jsonDeserializer);
}
```

Is this acceptable or is it just a work around?

Comment: Hard to really understand your exact issue, but if you are to send any (CustomObject) from Microservice A to Microservice B, they both have to have a POJO that understands how to deserialize (CustomObject) from its String format..

Comment: @SMA yes I do have a pojo in both microservices with the same rappresentation, I also tryied to define a custom deserializer extending the jsonDeserializer but I am still getting the errors.

Comment: According to the error, ClassNotFoundException means your consumer doesn't have any known class by that package + name. Where are you even using the Message class in the consumer code?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I've added an edit whit the question you asked, I saw some other solution saying to map in both the producer and consumer the class that is being serialized and deserialized as per the official documentation but it's not working, I've also tryed to add the ErrorHandlingDeserializer with no results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you send a message to kafka, a header is sent along with the message. Inside the header, by default, is the full address of the Custom Object.

For example:

```
 com.example.kafkaproducer.model.Message
```

The consumer side of the message class must be created in the same path of the producer. Because validation is done when receiving the message on the consumer side, if a path other than the path is specified, the following error is received.

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.kafkaproducer.model.Message

Most likely, if you change the Message class path on the consumer side, your error will be fixed.

Comment: oh ok, it makes sense now, I did not understand why the consumer was looking for the model class with the producer address. Thanks! I can not upvote your answer because I have a low reputatuion, I marked it as solved tho.

Comment: When you set the second parameter Jsonserializer <> (Message.class, false)
equal false, the package address is no longer important on the consumer side, and you can create anywhere Message class.